# How to create a data frame from the all possible combination of values of each of the categories listed in the large dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pyspark, iterator, multiprocessing

I would like to create a data frame from the all possible combination of values of each of the categories listed in the dictionary.

I tried the below code, it is working fine for small dictionary with lesser key and values. But it is not getting executed for larger dictionary as i have given below.

```
import itertools as it
import pandas as pd 


my_dict= {
    "A":[0,1,.....25],
    "B":[4,5,.....35],
    "C":[0,1,......30],
    "D":[0,1,........35], 
       ......... 
    "Y":[0,1,........35],
    "Z":[0,1,........35],
}
df=pd.DataFrame(list(it.product(*my_dict.values())), columns=my_dict.keys())
```

This is the error i get, how to handle this problem with large dictionary.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-11-723405257e95>", line 1, in <module>
    df=pd.DataFrame(list(it.product(*my_dict.values())), columns=my_dict.keys())
```

MemoryError

How to handle with the large dictionary to create data frame

Comment: @Brown Bear, Thanks for your answer. As you said, it take a long time. I executed the code with few dictionary keys and values but it is still executing for more than 2 hours. Do you have any suggestion to make it efficient. I have 80 keys and around 30+ values. I think this will not be possible to create a data frame with this volume.

Comment: Do you want to tell, what you want to evaluate when you have this huge dataframe ? When thinking in algorithms, I can imagine that is not necessary to create this huge dataframe explicitely. E.g. `my_dict` can be transformed in a numpy-array with `Z` dimensions. With a Markov Chain Monte Carlo method (MCMC)  one migth access randomly and build the combinatorial values., when they are needed. 
But as mentioned already: it depends on the intention.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a *sufficiently large* <sup>[1]</sup> Spark cluster, each list in dictionary can be used as a Spark dataframe and then all these dataframes can be [cross-joined](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.crossJoin.html):

```python
def to_spark_dfs(dict):
    for key in dict:
        l=[[e] for e in dict[key]]
        yield spark.createDataFrame(l, schema=[key])

dfs=to_spark_dfs(my_dict)

from functools import reduce
res=reduce(lambda df1,df2: df1.crossJoin(df2),dfs)
```

If the original `my_dict` is not too large

```python
my_dict= {
    "A":[0,1,2],
    "B":[4,5,6],
    "C":[0,1,2],
    "D":[0,1], 
    "Y":[0,1,2],
    "Z":[0,1],
}
```

the code produces the expected result:

```python
res.show()
#+---+---+---+---+---+---+
#|  A|  B|  C|  D|  Y|  Z|
#+---+---+---+---+---+---+
#|  0|  4|  0|  0|  0|  0|
#|  0|  4|  0|  0|  0|  1|
#|  0|  4|  0|  0|  1|  0|
#|  0|  4|  0|  0|  1|  1|
#...

res.count()
#324
```

<sup>[1]</sup>
Using the numbers given in the comment (80 keys and approx 30 values per key) you would need a *really large* Spark cluster: `30 ^ 80` gives  `1.5*10^118` different combination. This is more than the estimated [number of atoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_universe#Matter_content%E2%80%94number_of_atoms/) (`10^80`) in the known, observable universe.

Answer (score 2):

In your case you can not generate all possible combination at once, by using the `list()` but do it in loop, for example:

```
import itertools as it
import pandas as pd
from string import ascii_uppercase

N = 36
my_dict = {x: list(range(N)) for x in ascii_uppercase}
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=my_dict.keys())

for row in it.product(*my_dict.values()):
    df.loc[len(df.index)] = row
```

but of cause it take a long time

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you said, it take a long time. I executed the code with few dictionary keys and values but it is still executing for more than 3 hours. I have 80 keys and around 30+ values each. I think this is impossible to create a data frame with this volume. Do you have any suggestion to make it efficient?

Comment: you can try to implement some code using the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) I will try do it but not today.

Comment: I think one possibility is there by creating the sub dictionary of 3 values for each key by random sample and then create a smaller data frame , then append all the smaller data frame to create larger data frame.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, we have a *huge number of possible combinations*. For example, if columns (A, B, C... Z) can take values [1...10] then total count of rows are equal 10^26, or 100000000000000000000000000.

In my mind there are 2 main directions to solve this issue:

- **Horizontal scaling**: calculate and store results using frameworks for distributed computing (such as `Apache Spark` or `Hadoop`)
- **Vertical scaling**: optimize CPU/RAM utilization using:

  - Vectorization (e.g. avoid `loops`)
  - Data types with minimal impact to RAM allocation (use as minimal precision as you need, use `factorize()` for strings)
  - mini-batching and download intermediate results (data frames) from RAM to disc in zipped format (e.g. `parquet`)
  - benchmark the execution time and object size in RAM.

Let me introduce the code that implements some of the concepts of the vertical scaling approach.

Define the following functions:

- `create_data_frame_baseline()`: data frame generator with loop, not optimal data types (baseline)
- `create_data_frame_no_loop()`: no loop, not optimal data types
- `create_data_frame_optimize_data_type()`: no loop, optimal data types.

```py
import itertools as it
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from string import ascii_uppercase


def create_letter_dict(cols_n: int = 10, levels_n: int = 6) -> dict:
    letter_dict = {letter: list(range(levels_n)) for letter in ascii_uppercase[0:cols_n]}
    return letter_dict


def create_data_frame_baseline(dict: dict) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=dict.keys())
    for row in it.product(*dict.values()):
        df.loc[len(df.index)] = row
    
    return df


def create_data_frame_no_loop(dict: dict) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return pd.DataFrame(
        list(it.product(*dict.values())),
        columns=dict.keys()
    )


def create_data_frame_optimize_data_type(dict: dict) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return pd.DataFrame(
        np.int8(list(it.product(*dict.values()))),
        columns=dict.keys()
    )
```

Benchmarks:

```py
import sys
import timeit

cols_n = 7
levels_n = 5
iteration_n = 2


# Baseline

def create_data_frame_baseline_test():
    my_dict = create_letter_dict(cols_n, levels_n)
    df = create_data_frame_baseline(my_dict)

    assert(df.shape == (levels_n**cols_n, cols_n))
    print(sys.getsizeof(df))

    return df

print(timeit.Timer(create_data_frame_baseline_test).timeit(number=iteration_n))


# No loop, not optimal data types 

def create_data_frame_no_loop_test():
    my_dict = create_letter_dict(cols_n, levels_n)
    df = create_data_frame_no_loop(my_dict)

    assert(df.shape == (levels_n**cols_n, cols_n))
    print(sys.getsizeof(df))

    return df

print(timeit.Timer(create_data_frame_no_loop_test).timeit(number=iteration_n))


# No loop, optimal data types.

def create_data_frame_optimize_data_type_test():
    my_dict = create_letter_dict(cols_n, levels_n)
    df = create_data_frame_optimize_data_type(my_dict)

    assert(df.shape == (levels_n**cols_n, cols_n))
    print(sys.getsizeof(df))

    return df

print(timeit.Timer(create_data_frame_optimize_data_type_test).timeit(number=iteration_n))
```

Outputs*:

| Function | Dataframe shape | RAM size, Mb | Execution time, sec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| create_data_frame_baseline_test | 78125x7 | 19 | 485 |
| create_data_frame_no_loop_test | 78125x7 | 4.4 | 0.20 |
| create_data_frame_optimize_data_type_test | **78125x7** | **0.55** | **0.16** |

Using `create_data_frame_optimize_data_type_test()` I generated* **100M rows in less than 100 seconds**.

* Ubuntu Server 20.04, Intel(R) Xeon(R) 8xCPU @ 2.60GHz, 32GB RAM

Comment: good answer but for big value your version doesn't work. I mean you don't solve the question.

Comment: @BrownBear but your answer below doesn't solve the question also. Moreover, looks like that your solution is slower than my proposal.

Comment: Yeap I know that my answer doesn't solve the issue, that is why I made bounty the question. And I up voted your answer, but not ready to  give the bounty to you.

Comment: Sorry about the little misunderstanding there. Thanks for the feedback!